# Можно ли присвоить значение, будто его набрал человек?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

у меня есть кнопка, которая присваивает значение одному из трёх полей, которые отвечают за подсчет Главного поля. Вот это присваивание:

```
$('#veh_type_code')[0].value = data.answer["VehicleCategory2"];
```

Значение присваивается, но как-то "не четко". Когда мы присвоили и начинаем писать данные в след. поля - присвоенное значение слетает.
Отчего это происходит: Есть функция на vue js, которая постоянно смотрит вводит ли пользователь данные, чтобы подсчитать из них троих "Главное input поле", и когда мы вводим любые данные в одно из оставшихся 2 полей - она скидывает не "onChanged" поля.
Дак вот, могу ли я изменить как-то присваивание значения, чтобы его замечал скрипт? Написать его на Vue, например?

Comment: Не надо ставить теги, не относящиеся к вопросу

Comment: @Ипатьев да как не относящиеся?? это чисто по php вопрос

Comment: попробуй набрать в браузере фразу "на каком языке написан vue.js". Ответ тебя немного удивит

Comment: @Ипатьев на js и typescript и?

Comment: молодец. теперь ты знаешь, какие теги ставить этому вопросу

Comment: @ипатьев код написан на php и vue js, мб прочитаете еще раз пост и поймете, что тут нужны знания человека связанного с php и js

Comment: ну хорошо. я даю тебе возможность попробовать объяснить, при чем здесь РНР. Чисто для того чтобы ты сам в процессе разобрался, что к чему. Для начала можешь привести здесь РНР код, который, по-твоему, работает неправильно

Comment: Мне вообще интересно. Как это автор себе представляет. Php это бекенд. Vue фронт. Меняется что то на фронте и кто или что должно случится на php

Comment: да, я понял, спасибо

Comment: jquery *тоже* не имеет отношения к vue :)

Comment: просто тут присваивание происходит на jquery.. мне получается надо изменить присваивание на язык vue?

Comment: Хотелось бы напомнить, что `jquery` - это лишь обёртка над `JavaScript` и никакого "языка  Vue" не существует. Вам стоит получше разобраться в том, как работает Vue и JavaScript в целом.

Comment: Согласен, а по задаче, может как-то jquery влиять на vue? Или причина в чем-то другом?

Comment: Может. Смешивать их не рекомендуется